# ComboBox с элементами управления

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Подскажите, можно ли сделать так, что бы при нажатии на элемент ComboBox выдвигались не список значений, а вдвигалась форма на которой перечислены кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это называется Split Button и в .NET и доступен для панелей инструментов, но не для использования в обычных WinForms. 
Тем не менее, существуют некоторые альтернативные варианты, такие как:

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18447/SplitButton-a-NET-WinForm-control-Part-1)

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15627/SplitButton-an-XP-style-dropdown-split-button)

Или используйте WPF

Comment: Я ,немного, обновил вопрос. Дополнил скриншотом.

Comment: В winform это сделать достаточно проблематично, проще использовать готовые компоненты сторонних разработчиков или создавать свой контрол

Comment: А есть что-нибудь бесплатное? Я только знаю DevExpress и он платный.

Comment: Я же в ответе указал ссылки